# Change var values = [2, 3, 4] to something like [all whole numbers]

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, yui3

Here's a another noob question.

Again working with YUI3.

How can I change:

```
var values = [2, 3, 4];
```

to include ALL whole numbers, and not just 2, 3, and 4 ?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's a bit of extra info.

This is what I have:

```
var numbers = [2, 3, 4];

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
  var boxnum = numbers[i];
  Y.all(".box"+boxnum ).addClass(boxnum );  
}
```

so just want to check for each possible class of . box1, .box2, .box3, .... ,but I'm not sure how many of these classes there might be.

Ta!

Comment: `ALL whole numbers` is an infinite list.... why do you want to do that

Comment: well in my scenario there could probably be maximum 10, but there might be 12 or 13. I am finding classes in code with those numbers in it. I thought there might be an easy way like [n] or sthing similar, or maybe [2,...] or sthing like that. Nevermind though fellas, if it can't be done easily then I'll just put a whole bunch of numbers in there!

Comment: Which brings us to the real question - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have added a bit to my question to show the context Im using this in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Find all elements with class "box" + x:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= 9999; x++) {
    if ($('.box' + x).length < 1) {
        $('.box' + x).addClass('yourClass');
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

This assumes you wont have box x if you don't have box (x-1). (boxes are numbered in order without any missing numbers) If this assumption is not correct, let me know.

Comment: Yep, watson, something like that, I have updated my question.

Comment: I don't use yui, so someone else might have to answer your question, but what you want is definitely possible. I could tell you how to do it with jQuery :]

Comment: jquery might be fine, it would give me an idea!

Comment: thanks, but what do I put between the brackets here then: var levels = [2, 3, 4]; ?

Comment: OK nevermind Watson, I got this working now! Thanks!

Comment: Are you potentially calling the jQuery function `1000` times?

Answer (score 0):

for some reason I would not recommend looping through and calling the `jQuery` function 1000 times, I would recommend you call it once. Something like this perhaps

```
var elements = $('*').filter( function() { 
    return /box[0-9]/.test( this.className )
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qjVsU/**

**Benchmarks: http://jsperf.com/class-starts-with-selector-jquery**

Comment: This does not cover **0-9** it covers any class like this for example `box-923937598792357958713985651087307598`, `[0-9]` means any number between 0 and 9 any number of times

Comment: `box923937598792357958713985651087307598` Will Work and so will this `box23` and this `box2434` and this `box1`

Comment: Your answer might be better than mine, but using $('*') is probably not a good idea. That could easily take longer than calling $ 100 times. Can you think of a way to put $('box' + x) there instead?

Comment: Ill do a jsperf.com later

Comment: Try it on a page with some svgs ;)

Comment: I can't event seem to get yours to work http://jsfiddle.net/SUhFb/ @watson

Comment: In, **Chrome** your answer is **85%** Slower and it is **58%** slower in **FireFox** @watson

Comment: Depending on what page you use it on. If you have a page with tons of elements (why i mentioned svgs), it would change things. But alas, i suppose i will concede that your answer is better.